# Why CollectionView cell insider other collectionView has wrong size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView (nested) inside a collectionViewCell. When I open this VC, the cell inside nested collectionView have wrong size. After scroll down and up - everything is fine.
I think when I am scrolling method `layoutSubviews` are calling.
But when I added
`cell.setNeedsLayout() cell.layoutIfNeeded()`
inside `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` the result is not change.
[image]

[image]

Constraints:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is not with the size, it is from constraints.

Would you please share a snippet of your code

Comment: I have added screenshot of the constraints